# Issue in passing value from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have one view controller. I added popoverviewcontroller on button action and loaded another viewcontroller which has a uitableview controller. When I select a value inside the tableview controller, I am not able to pass the selected value into firstviewcontroller.

The value is coming as null

Second ViewController is having UITableview

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RemovePopOverController" object:self];
    selectedValue =   [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

firstviewController

```
-(void)removePopOver:(id)sender{

    [self->popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    NSString *value = m_titleViewController.selectedValue; 


  NSLog(@" Value is %@", value);
}
```

I don't want to use NSUserDefault. Please advice me with a solution for this issue!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the notification before setting the value. Try doing it like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    selectedValue =   [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RemovePopOverController" object:self];
}
```

Comment: Still its null value i am getting  even change it!

Comment: Without seeing more code I don't know what else to suggest. Try implementing the setSelectedValue method manually and putting a breakpoint to see if something else is nil-ing the value out?

Answer (score 0):

Use **delegate** for your requirement as it best pratcice to use in this situation rather than posting notification.

Refer [simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) link. Hope helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Then you can use Another method like This :

Create a String in Appdelegate (ex: stringValue)

First save your Value into your Appdelegate:

```
 Appdelegate *appdell=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appdell.stringValue=@"Your Value Goes Here";
```

when ever you want you can get this value.

```
Appdelegate *appdell=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

requiredvalue=appdell.stringValue;
```

Comment: This is a sub-optimal architecture though, and turns your app delegate into a dumping ground for random data. It's much better to correctly define and implement sensible relationships between objects in your application.

Comment: As I mentioned, using the app delegate to shuttle around random data is a poor architecture choice. Using globals is just as bad maybe worse. Among other things, you have tightly coupled all your code to the application delegate when there was no good reason too.